# Create Pivots tables for all sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a report that  separate to multiple sheets based on a column and then rename them as per the values in that referenced column. Could someone help me adding pivot tables for each of the sheet in this workbook ?. For Ex. I have 4 sheets named abc, def, ghi, jkl, so I need new sheets created like abc_Pivot, def_Pivot and so on with pivot tables from the corresponding sheets.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is not a code writing service!

Answer (score 0):

PivotTables have an inbuilt feature called Show Report Filter Pages that lets you create new sheets each with a version of the PivotTable automatically filtered on each criteria. To use this, make the field a PageField (i.e. put it in the Filters area) and then select Analyze>Options>Show Report Filter Pages.

Check out YouTube for examples..look for videos from Mike Girvin (ExcelIsFun) or Debra Dalgleish (Contextures) or Bill Jelen (Mr Excel) for starters.

Comment: @PrabhakarDas if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.